# Data Structure for Stadium Seating

Tags: java, sql, data-structures

For a Java application for the booking and ticketing of a stadium, I would like to plan individual seats in the stadium. So when graphically shown they can be selected and booked etc.

I have thought about a multidimensional array of 'seat' objects. These would contain data about the seat, such as category, location, availability(booked) etc. Eg:

```
Seat[][]
```

So, after selecting which block in the stadium for example, and then navigating to a seat with [5][8] for rows and columns. I could iterate over this to display the layout and show available seats or already sold etc.

Firstly, what would be an ideal way to achieve this with arrays? I need to basic things, changing the object in the array and iterating.

Secondly, how could this be achieved in a very different way, so multiple clients can modify the data. With customer data, I have a SQL database, do multiple clients can use the system, not a local file saved. 
I am struggling to think of a way to use SQL to represent seats like this.

The trouble is I am unsure how to structure an SQL table to this effect. I could use arrays, but this doesn't fill the full functionality I would want.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but generally speaking when I go to a stadium, my ticket is located by section, row, seat, in that order... So, shouldn't your data structures be similar?

Comment: Yep, I was planning on using just (5,6) for row and seat, and ignored the section/block in my question, I think I can sort that easily.

Comment: Downvotes, why? I can modify the question if you say how.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little confusing because you didn't specify exactly what objects are going inside of this array. I will assume that you meant a multidimensional array of `Seat` objects. If not, replace `Seat` with whatever object you are putting there.

For the multidimensional array of seats, you have two main options: First and most simple, is to find the length of the longest row, and define the length of your array to that size. Of course with that set up, you will have some spots in the array where simply no seat exists. You could simply fill all of those non-existent seat spots with `null`.

The second and probably better method to use, would be to create a jagged array. You should of course know what the length of each row should be beforehand so you can create the proper number of columns. A [jagged array](http://way2java.com/arrays/jagged-arrays-varying-column-size-arrays/) doesn't have the same number of columns for each row. Your code would look something like this:

```
int numRows=//Number of rows in stadium
int[] numCol=//Number of columns in each row
Seat[][] stadium = new Seat[numRows][]; //Defines stadium without specifying # of columns
for(int i=0; i<stadium.length; i++)
{
    stadium[i]=new Seat[numCol[i]]; //Creates each row with correct number of columns
}
```

Adapt this code to work in yor own program of course. Remember that iterating through `stadium` will require you to check the length of each row.

When it comes to making it editable by multiple clients, you have to be more specific with your question. You may be able to have your java program access the values in the SQL table and assign them to values in the multidimensional array. If you cannot do that, then you can have the java program run and [accept arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) to assign to your values in the array. To get a more specific answer however, you need to ask a more specific question.

Good luck!